# Add class to div with number increasing for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I'm wanting to add a class 'slide-number-x' to an element within each slide in a slider, with the 'x' representing the slide number in the dom.

So, for example this simple HTML markup:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
    <div class="slide"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
    <div class="slide"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
    <div class="slide"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
</div>
```

Would become:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide-number-1"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
    <div class="slide slide-number-2"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
    <div class="slide slide-number-3"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
    <div class="slide slide-number-4"><div class="slide-title"></div></div>
</div>
```

I thought this would work:

```
$('.slide').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slide-number'i+1);
});
```

Any help or ideas?

Many thanks,
R

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the concatenation operator (`+`), use:

```
$('.slide').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slide-number-' + (i+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be:

```
$(this).addClass('slide-number-' + (i + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you what you want

```
$('.slide').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slide-number-' + (i+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're + is in the wrong place... Try this. It worked for me...

```
$('.slide').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slide-number'+i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the concatenation operator. Also, the convention for incrementing a value in JavaScript is the the double plus.

```
$('.slide').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slide-number-' + ++i);
});
```